# My gallery intent is not showing images ? why?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

this is a code to insert image into database. the problem is when  use the function "requestWritePermission();" then I cant get into this activity from another but when I remove this function.. This activity starts but when click on upload image button it gets into gallery but shows no image.. I am not getting it. Please help.

package com.example.tariqziad.myapplication;

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import static android.R.attr.id;

public class ImageUpload extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button uploadbutton, insertbutton;
    ImageView imageView;
    String mediaPath;
    private static final int WRITE_PERMISSION = 0x01;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_upload);
        //requestWritePermission();


        uploadbutton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);
        insertbutton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.insert);

        insertbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadpic();
            }
        });


        uploadbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,PICK_IMAGE);

            }
        });

        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                // Get the Image from data
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                assert cursor != null;
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                // Set the Image in ImageView for Previewing the Media
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
                cursor.close();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image/Video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void uploadpic() {
        File file = new File(mediaPath);

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);
        RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());
        SchoolInterfaces t=SchoolApi.getClient().create(SchoolInterfaces.class);
        Call<ImageResponse> call=t.uploadFile(fileToUpload,filename);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ImageResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ImageResponse> call, Response<ImageResponse> response) {
                ImageResponse serverResponse = response.body();
                if (serverResponse != null) {
                    if (serverResponse.getSuccess()) {
                      /* Intent intent=new Intent(PostArea.this,SellerActivity.class);
                       intent.putExtra("id",id);
                       startActivity(intent); */
                        //finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    assert serverResponse != null;
                    Log.v("Response", serverResponse.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ImageResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == WRITE_PERMISSION){
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "You must allow permission write external storage to your mobile device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void requestWritePermission() {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you try to add permissions to the manifest file, instead of trying to make request with the java code? Sometimes it happens because on runtime the app doesn't have the permission it acts like it never has it even after providing it programmatically.

Comment: ok I did it that way but it is not showing images when the gallery opens